# onBlockActivated block GUI

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I'm trying to follow a tutorial on how to program a block with a GUI in 1.15.2, but when creating onBlockActivated it want me to remove the @Override annotation, but in doing so keeps it from working.

```
public class BasicGenerator extends Block {

    public BasicGenerator() {
        super(Properties.create(Material.IRON).sound(SoundType.METAL).hardnessAndResistance(2.0f).lightValue(14));
        setRegistryName("basicgen");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasTileEntity(BlockState state) {
        return true;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public TileEntity createTileEntity(BlockState state, IBlockReader world) {
        return new BasicGenTile();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBlockPlacedBy(World world, BlockPos pos, BlockState state, @Nullable LivingEntity entity, ItemStack stack) {
        if (entity != null) {
            world.setBlockState(pos, state.with(BlockStateProperties.FACING, getFacingFromEntity(pos, entity)), 2);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public ActionResultType onBlockActivated(BlockState state, World world, BlockPos pos, PlayerEntity player, Hand hand, BlockRayTraceResult trace) {
        if (!world.isRemote) {
            TileEntity tileEntity = world.getTileEntity(pos);
            if (tileEntity instanceof INamedContainerProvider) {
                NetworkHooks.openGui((ServerPlayerEntity) player, (INamedContainerProvider) tileEntity, tileEntity.getPos());
            } else {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Our named container provider is missing!");
            }
            return ActionResultType.SUCCESS;
        }
        return super.onBlockActivated(state, world, pos, player, hand, trace);
    }

    public static Direction getFacingFromEntity(BlockPos clickedBlock, LivingEntity entity) {
        Vec3d vec = entity.getPositionVec();
        return Direction.getFacingFromVector((float) (vec.x - clickedBlock.getX()), (float) (vec.y - clickedBlock.getY()), (float) (vec.z - clickedBlock.getZ()));
    }

    @Override
    protected void fillStateContainer(StateContainer.Builder<Block, BlockState> builder) {
        builder.add(BlockStateProperties.FACING);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify a bit? What wants to remove annotation and what doesn't work. As for annotation it may be better to stay just from generic java code perspective.

Comment: I'm currently using eclipse IDE to code the mod, eclipse says to remove the @Override anotation, but if i do so and try to interact the block ingame, the GUI will not display, the onBlockActivated is what tells the game to display the GUI

Comment: Do you inherit from object or interface woth this method?

Comment: I edited the question to show the whole class, sorry, i don't understand what your meaning.

Comment: @logan63049 add the 'java' tag to this for more visibility.

Comment: And what is the code for Block class? Or documentation?

Comment: Is there a website i can use to put the code at, the class is over 1200 lines of code

Comment: https://pastebin.com/1jgss93F

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to update your mappings (in the build.gradle file).
Look at http://export.mcpbot.bspk.rs for the up to date mappings, and replace the line in your build.gradle.